# Difference among You never change. and You change never. and Never do you change

Tags: grammar, adverbs, negation

I think "You never change." is the most usual and basic. But "You change never." is also well used in spoken English. "Never do you change." is almost never seen on books and heard in conversations.
I just learned it from an English grammar so-called "inversion with negative adverb" like "Neither does she.", "Nor do I.". More examples are

> I can be blamed for the accident in no way. -> In no way can I be blamed for the accident.
>
> One seldom sees acts of charity. -> Seldom does one see acts of charity.

Largely when is the third form used? Is it just a usage of dead language?

Comment: I have not once heard *you change never* before. Where, exactly, have you found that phrase to be "well used"?

Comment: I found it from a movie's translated subtitles. all of them seem to be American English.

Comment: I can't say with certainty if *you change never* is actually ungrammatical (there is no strict rule on adverb placement), but since I speak English natively, and I've never once heard it used in Canada, the US, or the UK, I'm fairly confident it's uncommon to the point of being essentially wrong—or it's only used in a specific dialect that I'm unfamiliar with. I think it's more likely that the movie's subtitles were wrong. (And a single movie's subtitles shouldn't be used to justify the phrasing as "well used.")

Comment: Movie subtitles are notoriously untrustworthy.

Comment: Native English speaker. I, too, have heard never someone say, "You change never." ;)